# Problem trying to insert records with foreign keys in php fat free framework and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, post, fat-free-framework

I need to insert the record in the `usuarios` table, then in the `personas` table using the foreign key `id_usuario` and finally insert the record in the `usuarios_roles` table using the foreign key `id_usuario` as well. I am working with PHP Fat Free Framework.
This is my form to register a persona in my view record.html (please ignore blank inputs):

```
<form action="registroEmpresa" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rut" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre_razonsocial" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono" />
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" />
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
    <?php $empty = ' '; ?>
    <input id="" name="apellidos" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $empty; ?>">
    <input id="" name="direccion" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $empty; ?>">
    <input id="" name="pais" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $empty; ?>">
    <input id="" name="region" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $empty; ?>">
    <input id="" name="ciudad" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $empty; ?>">
     <input id="" name="comuna" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $empty; ?>">
    <button type="submit">Registrarme</button>
</form>
```

I must follow this relational model that connects the table `personas` with the table `usuarios` and in turn `usuarios_roles`. Primary keys are all self-incremental: (
[Relational MySQL Model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b0-HO2lbBTZrT4US665X7Ovzn3gtXQMz/view?usp=sharing))

Now comes the part that I don't understand how to program. At the time of doing the `save()` I can register a user, but when I do the `save()` of persona obviously it will not be linked to the `id_usuario` and there will not be an `INSERT` in the table `usuarios_roles`. Currently I receive the information in my index.php specifically here:

```
$f3->route('POST @registroEmpresa: /registroEmpresa',
function($f3) {
    $db = getConnection(); 

    $usuario = new DB\SQL\Mapper($db, 'usuarios'); 
    $usuario->copyFrom('POST');
    $usuario->save();   //insert new usuario row    
    
    $persona = new DB\SQL\Mapper($db, 'personas'); 
    $persona->copyFrom('POST');
    $persona->save();   //insert new persona row (without foreign key ;C  )   

    //get credentials
    $email = $f3->get('POST.email');
    $password = $f3->get('POST.password'); 

    //bad practices to add "id_usuario" to personas table
    $db->exec("UPDATE `personas` 
               SET `id_usuario` = (SELECT `id_usuario` FROM `usuarios`
                                    WHERE `email` = '$email' and `password` = '$password')
               ORDER BY `id_persona` DESC
               LIMIT 1"); 

    //bad practices to add "id_usuario" to usuarios_roles table
    $db->exec("INSERT INTO `usuarios_roles`(`id_usuario`, `id_rol`) VALUES
             (( SELECT `id_usuario` FROM `usuarios`
                WHERE `email` = '$email' and `password` = '$password'ORDER BY `id_usuario` DESC
               LIMIT 1),5)"); 

    echo View::instance()->render('login.html');
});
```

Do you have any PHP fat-free code or idea that can serve me for this purpose, without using updates, inserts, or SQL queries? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might be after is available in a plugin called `f3-cortex`. In there, there's a specific section about relations that may be of benefit to what you're trying to accomplish. https://github.com/ikkez/f3-cortex#relations There are 1:1, 1:many, many:many relationships that you can set up that will take care of what you need.

> With Cortex you can create associations between multiple models. By linking them together, you can create all common relationships you need for smart and easy persistence.